# How to mod_rewrite to redirect specific string length?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is what i'm trying to do : when someone access my site using a fixed 32 char string 'folder', it will redirect for a specific site passing this string as parameter

For instance :

```
www.example.com/29fe7a48516763c7c3033929e3d4c2a0
```

Will redirect to

```
www.example.com/myurl?param=29fe7a48516763c7c3033929e3d4c2a0
```

This will apply only if the the `29fe7a48516763c7c3033929e3d4c2a0` folder does not exist and has 32 chars.

I need to use the .htaccess file to do this.

Comment: Where are these directives to be used? In `.htaccess` or server config? Are you sure you want an external "redirect" and not an internal "rewrite"? (A "redirect" would not strictly need mod_rewrite, unless you have existing mod_rewrite directives in the config file.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex quantifier `{n}` (where `n` is any number) to determine an exact number of the preceding token.

It looks like this is a hexadecimal string (letters `a-f` and digits `0-9` only), not literally any string, so the regex should match accordingly.

Using mod_rewrite you can then do the following to perform a "redirect" as in the example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[a-f0-9]{32}$ /myurl?param=$0 [R=302,L]
```

The above is a 302 (temporary) redirect. The `$0` backreference contains the entire match from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. the value of the 32 char hexdec string).

However, I would think this should probably be an *internal* "rewrite", as opposed to an *external* "redirect". ie. the URL should not change. If that is the case then the rule should be adjusted as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-f0-9]{32}$ myurl?param=$0 [L]
```

Note the removal of the `R` flag and the slash prefix on the *substitution* string. Note that `myurl` should be a relative filesystem path.

**UPDATE:** Since this is being used in `.htaccess`, you should remove the `/?` prefix on the regex (I've updated the above rules).

However, if this was to be used in a *server* or *virtualhost* context then you would need to change the rule like so:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-f0-9]{32})$ /myurl?param=$1 [R=302,L]
```

Note the slash prefix and additional parentheses in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (regex) and use of the `$1` backreference (instead of `$0`) in the *substitution* string. You could make the slash prefix *optional* to allow it to work in a *directory* (`.htaccess`) context as well.